# Hyperref: Why am I getting a fatal TeX capacity exceeded error?

Tags: hyperref, urls

I'm converting a document written for print distribution to one for electronic distribution by turning all of the URLs into hyperlinked URLs. Using the hyperref package and \url command. A single URL is giving me the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\font@name -> \OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95
l.4 .../$FILE/Open%20Meetings%20Law%20FAQ.pdf}

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on FSGuide2022ElecProbMinEx.log.
```

I can't figure out why.

Here's a minimal example (with the offending URL) that gives this behavior.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{https://app.lla.state.la.us/llala.nsf/BAADB2991272084786257AB8006EE827/\$FILE/Open\%20Meetings\%20Law\%20FAQ.pdf} 
\end{document}
```

I'm probably making some silly mistake, but I can't for the life of me see what it is!

Thanks

Comment: hyperref doesn't like the `\$`,  use only `$`.

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` works too.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you, thank you! That did it.

Answer (score 1):

There's something fundamentally wrong with the URL string shown in your posting. Specifically, why are the `$` and `%20` particles escaped with backslash characters?

In my view, both of the following versions of the URL string are correct -- observe that neither makes use of `\` characters to "escape" TeX-special characters such as `$` and `%`.

```
https://app.lla.state.la.us/llala.nsf/BAADB2991272084786257AB8006EE827/$FILE/Open Meetings Law FAQ.pdf

https://app.lla.state.la.us/llala.nsf/BAADB2991272084786257AB8006EE827/$FILE/Open%20Meetings%20Law%20FAQ.pdf
```

Sure enough, the test program

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\begin{document}
\url{https://app.lla.state.la.us/llala.nsf/BAADB2991272084786257AB8006EE827/$FILE/Open Meetings Law FAQ.pdf}

\url{https://app.lla.state.la.us/llala.nsf/BAADB2991272084786257AB8006EE827/$FILE/Open%20Meetings%20Law%20FAQ.pdf}
\end{document}
```

yields the following screenshot:

[image]

Happily, clicking on both hyperlinks sends you to the correct file.